# Leaflet: missing tiles when serving external tilesets

Tags: node.js, express, leaflet

I've configured my Express app to grab tiles from a tile server and then display them using Leaflet. The reason I'm doing this is to hide the API key. I understand that this is likely to slow performance, but I couldn't think of another way of making sure the API key is kept off of the client side.

Anyways, it mostly works, but sometimes random tiles just don't show up. I noticed that in the debug terminal, some GET requests just... don't get a response?

Any reason why this would happen? Any better ways of approaching this problem? Thanks.

**Controller:**

```js
const request = require('request');
require('dotenv').config()

exports.get_tileset = function(req, res, next) {
    
    var api_key = process.env.PLANET_API_KEY

    var tile_url = 'https://tiles1.planet.com/data/v1/' + req.params.itemtype +'/' + req.params.id + '/' + req.params.z + '/' + req.params.x + '/' + req.params.y + '.png?api_key=' + api_key

    var requestSettings = {
        url: tile_url,
        method: 'GET',
        encoding: null
    };

    request(requestSettings, function(error, response, body) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
        res.send(body);
    });

}
```

**Debug terminal:**

```
GET /planetTileset/PSScene4Band/20211001_191039_42_240f/11/322/702 200 110.642 ms - 820
GET /planetTileset/PSScene4Band/20211001_191039_42_240f/11/323/702 200 136.732 ms - 820
GET /planetTileset/PSScene4Band/20211001_191039_42_240f/11/322/700 - - ms - -
GET /planetTileset/PSScene4Band/20211001_191039_42_240f/11/321/700 - - ms - -
GET /planetTileset/PSScene4Band/20211001_191039_42_240f/11/324/699 - - ms - -
GET /planetTileset/PSScene4Band/20211001_191039_42_240f/11/321/699 - - ms - -
GET /planetTileset/PSScene4Band/20211001_191039_42_240f/11/324/702 - - ms - -
GET /planetTileset/PSScene4Band/20211001_191039_42_240f/11/321/702 - - ms - -
GET /planetTileset/PSScene4Band/20211001_191039_42_240f/12/644/1401 200 166.215 ms - 5222
GET /planetTileset/PSScene4Band/20211001_191039_42_240f/12/645/1401 200 169.532 ms - 21774
GET /planetTileset/PSScene4Band/20211001_191039_42_240f/12/645/1400 200 246.122 ms - 78025
```

Comment: For the requests that do not receive a response from your Tile server, what happens if you directly call them from a browser?

Comment: @ghybs : load fine as single PNG files